# Using PHP array in a SQL query in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, sql, laravel-5

I'm a beginner in Laravel. I have faced a issue in using a PHP array in a SQL statement. I have a array `$waypoints`and it contains names of cities.

`$waypoints = array("Paris", "Moscow", "London","New York");`

And i want to find their corresponding city `id` by a SQL query. Code is as follow.

```
$cityname = $waypoints[2];

$city = City::where('name', 'LIKE', "$cityname%")->firstOrFail();
```

But this query does not get executed. But if i set a string value to variable   `$cityname` manually, it get executed. As example `$cityname = "London";`. 
 I can't figure out the issue. Help Needed.

Comment: `London` has the index `2`, not `3`. We start counting on `0`. What is `print_r($waypoints)`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt `London` was just an example.

Comment: I am not familar with laravel, but as long `$cityname = "London"` works, `$waypoints[2]` is not `"London"`. See `var_dump($waypoints)`

Comment: Do you see any errors?

Comment: var_dump($waypoints) is as follows. `array (size=4)'
  0 => string 'Paris' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Moscow' (length=6)
  2 => string 'London' (length=6)
  3 => string 'New York' (length=8)`

Comment: What is `City::where('name', 'LIKE', "$cityname%")->toSql();`? What is `var_dump($city)`?

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt var_dump($city) is like this. `string 'select * from \`cities\` where \`name\` LIKE ? ' (length=42)`

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt `City::where('name', 'LIKE', "$cityname%")->toSql();` is as follows. `select * from \`cities\` where \`name\` LIKE ?'`

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `->toSql();` to get the query string for debugging.